# Cross Domain Access for XML webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Domain Access with PHP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894822/cross-domain-access-with-php-proxy)

I'm trying to access a .net webservice provides xml responses. Now I have applicatin written in Mobile JQuery and due to cross-domain access problem I couldn't access the service.

Now there are many solutions.
1. Using flash(I do no want it as it should run on mobiles)
2. Using PHP or C# proxy (nope, this should be client site)

Any other way to break through cross domain access?? Any JavaScript libraries for it?? I searched like one week and still no luck. :(

Comment: do you have control over the server side?

Comment: yes. I can ask the service dev to make changes. thanks.

Comment: Checkout [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/). If the mobile devices/browsers you're targeting have good HTML5 support, specifically for [cross-domain communication](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/comms.html#crossDocumentMessages), then checkout this [article](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=109) on the underlying workings. I believe easyXDM already uses `window.postMessage` if the browser supports it.

Comment: can u please point me to a good easyXDM tutorial. exmples on site are too difficult to understand for a newbie like me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send reqeust via [PHP proxy](http://blog.michaelkidd.com/2007/10/php-ajax-proxy.html) and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the webservice you are trying to reach you could using JSONP. Just doing the request by using  GET insteed.  Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
If you want to pass some parameter you can also, if you know what you are doing, pass it with GET. For example the URL could be, yourdomain.com/?parameters={variable:value} and just JSON decode the querystring on the serverside.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/ASPNET_JSONP.aspx) it maybe help you!

Comment: can't use Jasonp as my service supports only XML.