# 2-step dynamical echo of a php in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

step 1: I have a form where input fields will be generated dynamically by innerHTML.

```
var d = document.getElementById("d1p_1");
d.innerHTML += "<input class='add' name='field_" + i + "' type='text'>";
```

step 2: now I would like to echo a php variable of each value to each dynamically generated input field. Something like:

```
d.innerHTML += "<input class='add' name='field_" + i + "' type='text' value='"<?php echo $field_" + i + "; ?>" + "'>
```

How can I archieve that?

Thanks in advance.

To give further information:

This is for a form where an user can add fields, depending from how many fields he needs and will be adding. Now it could be that an user adds more fields than he usually needs and enters data somewhere between field_1 and field_280. To catch the field_x where he entered data I need to echo the value of that input field.

```
$field_1 = value of field_1 if given;
...
$field_280 = value of field_280 if given;
```

The innerHTML will add the input fields dynamically by a counter for `i`. So I dont know what input will be given on which field. Thats why I need to generate the PHP echo part dynamical as well. Like:

```
<?php echo $field_" + i + "; ?>
```

The whole process:

form -> contains first just one input field (user will make some inputs) -> by clicking a button there will be added further input fields (1 click 1 field and user does not need to fill in data before he can add another fields) -> now imagine that a user will add 3 fields and has given input on first and third input field -> name="field_1" and name="field_3" ->

the name of each input field is generated by `i++` -> the value is empty otherwise the form will be posted -> now the user will submit the form.
this means the value to echo would be `$field_3 = (isset($_POST['field_3'])) ? $_POST['field_3']; : '';` -> this variable exist for all `i` so each variable is set in the php part before BUT to catch the right input `name="field_i"` with `$field_i` and to echo this match is the problem.

So by clicking submit the page would be reloaded and instead of only just one input field like from before now would be there 2 input fields. first would be name="field_1" and the second would be name="field_3" because user has left out input name="field_2" before. So name="field_3" needs to echo the right value depending from a dynamically generated `name="field_"+ i +"`what means that when the name tag is generated dynamically the php tag needs also to be generated dynamically to match each other.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173182/add-remove-input-field-dynamically-with-jquery ?

Comment: exactly, I already achieved that. the issue now deals with the `value=""`tag inside that. that needs to be filled by php.

Comment: If I understand you correctly than the value of the newly added item can only be produced on the server-side for some reason. So e.g. the front-end value of item 3 will something very unique that only the back-end can calculate. Why then not hook into the click event to add an input field and do a dynamic call to the backend (the php) to retrieve the value (as json/javascript) and show the returned value as the value of the newly created input box?

Comment: sounds good,  but I have no clue how to achieve that. can you support an exxample please?

Comment: Just a random stackoverflow item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894822/cross-domain-access-with-php-proxy but if you search for "javascript proxy" or that $.ajax one then you will find a gazillion blogposts. So as long as you can uniquely ID in the DOM the item that needs to be replaced after the javascript proxy call (which is called by your click new input field method) you can on return of this replace the value with whatever comes back from the javascript-proxy-to-php call. or here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

i is a JavaScript variable so including  it in a php declaration is giving you problems

You may implement your string concatenation out of the php code as follows

```
  <?php 
       $field_="stavo";
   ?>



  <script type="text/javascript">


     var i=10;
        var d = document.getElementById("d1p_1");
       d.innerHTML+= "<input class='add' name='field_" + i + "'    type='text'>"; 
       d.innerHTML += "<input class='add' name='field_" + i + "' type='text' value='<?php echo $field_; ?>"+i+"'>";

  </script>
```

Of course you must be having this in your Html

```
 <div id="d1p_1"></div>
```

Comment: hie I have posted the whole code which worked for me

Comment: seems like you missunderstood me. i do not have only one php variable. i have for each i an extra variable. So this is what i mean by dynamical.

Comment: That said avoid JavaScript Concatenation within php code <?php echo $field_" + i + "; ?> is wrong. replace it with <?php echo $field_; ?>" + i + "

Comment: `<?php echo $xdata_; ?>` can not work when the php bracket will be closed. `i` will be extended AFTER the php part. So what you would echo is a variable called `$field_` which does not exist. My issue deals exactly with that on how to dynamically add `i` to that php variable so that it will be `$field_i` and not like yours `$field_`

Comment: I am afraid you are trying to assign a JavaScript variable to php which is not possible unless you do a page reload which is not an option.